# Safari iOS 8.3 - space-around not working

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

I have got a simple CSS and HTML structure, that is not working properly on iOS 8.3 with the property `justify-content: space-around;` on iOS 8.3, on a safari. I tried with another iPad with a newest version and it displays it well.

```css
.backgrounds {
    height: 13.5vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.backgrounds img {
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgrounds">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-bkg="plains-bkg">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-bkg="island-bkg">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-bkg="mountain-bkg">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-bkg="forest-bkg">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-bkg="swamp-bkg">
</div>
```

In the Safari with iOS 8.3 the images are aligned at the center, which is good, but it's not applying the rule of space-around. I've tried with a space-between and that property does apply it.

Any workaround with this issue? The prefixes have been added with an auto-prefixer build with gulp.

Comment: maybe your safari version is too old to support your css property

Comment: @TimGerhard maybe it is, and maybe there can't be a real solution to solve it

Comment: Sometimes, when the `img` element is a flex item, it simpy doesn't behave well. If to wrap them, does that work in IOS 8.3 ? ... http://jsfiddle.net/c1Lh4qef/ ... if this work I can post it as an answer

Comment: let me check that @LGSon

Comment: @LGSon nothing, i wrapped them into a div every image, and does nothing with it the space-around, just as your fiddle

Comment: Okay, then we know that :)

Comment: aaarg that olded browsers/os ! one day they will merge all into one (hahaha no way that will occur)

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you just giving margin to the image?

```
.backgrounds img {
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:40px;
}
```

I just roughly guessed 40px but if fiddle around you should find the right value for you.

Comment: Well, padding cannot be, it will shrink the image, but with margin it can do the trick a bit, but you have to be careful not to break the other views in the others OS.

Comment: margin should be fine

Comment: Yes, in this case it can be "easy" as I know that there are 5 images and I know what vw margin to apply, but in other cases this could be a lottery if you apply arbitrary margins. Change the padding for margins and I would upvote it, not as the "solution" because it really isn't one. But thanks for your shot!

Comment: I changed it. I still dont really understand why your way isn't working. I checked it on caniuse.com and it should be fine.

Comment: I got two iPads, one with a better iOS than the other, I suppose the safari aswel. One renders the space-around properly well, and the other not. Maybe I cannot use that attribute in some older browsers, no matter what.